# How do I change this code to use request_uri()?

Tags: 7

I'm trying to write a patch to make a module follow the Drupal coding standards.

I get this complain and I don't know how to fix it.

> Line 148: the use of REQUEST_URI is prone to XSS exploits and does not work on IIS; use [`request_uri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7) instead [security_12] return "http" . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "s" : "") . "://" . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

The function using that code is the following one.

```php
function module_get_url() {
   return "http" . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "s" : "") . "://" . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
}
```

Should I change the code to the following one?

```php
function module_request_uri() {
  return "http" . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "s" : "") . "://" . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means replace `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with `request_uri()`.

So `module_get_url()` needs to change slightly.

```
function module_get_url() {
  $uri = request_uri();
  return "http" . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "s" : "") . "://" . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$uri}";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @clive it work. But now I have another issue because I do not know how to used this in a variable. I open another question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133969/request-uri-to-url because this is similar but different question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply swap out `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with [`request_uri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7).

The reasoning is that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is Apache specific.

From the function [documentation page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7):

> Returns the equivalent of Apache's $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable.
>
> Because $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is only available on Apache, we generate an equivalent using other environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function module_get_url() {
  return url(current_path(), array('absolute' => true));
}
```